# Why wont the function run?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain why the function below is not working (giving me an alert) when I try to call first(), however it works fine when I assign it to a new const?

```
const first = () => {
    const greet = "Hi";
    const second = () => {
        alert("greet");
    }
    return second; 
}

first() // does not work

const newFunc = first();
newFunc(); // works
```

Is this something specific to ES6 or am I missing something?

Thank you everyone! I had a brain fart, I kept focusing on the new syntax thinking that I made a mistake or it works in a different way, but I was never calling the second function returned by the first one. I changed it to:

```
const first = () => {
        const greet = "Hi";
        const second = () => {
            alert("greet");
        }
        return second; 
    }

    first()
```

It works now!

Comment: So this is the version that works? Could you show the version that *doesn't* work instead?

Comment: `first()` only returns a function object - therefor another set of () is needed to actually _call_ that returned function. It doesn't need assignment to `const newFunc` though - `first()();` would get you your alert as well.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you wondering why you don't get an alert from only calling `first()`?

Comment: You're returning a function object. It should be `first()()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` works just fine and returns the `second()` function, but I don't think you expected this. And your try to copy it used () and thus called it, returning the second function. After that `newFunc` contains `second` and calling it gives you the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

`first()` only returns a function object - therefor another set of `()` is needed to actually *call* that returned function.

It doesn't need assignment to `const newFunc` though - `first()();` would get you your alert as well.

---

This technique of having a function return another function, or an object that exposes several functions that can then in turn be called, is know as *Revealing Module Pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning "second" as a function, but you never execute, you have 2 options, return "second()" or execute after receive it.

```js
const first = () => {
    const greet = "Hi";
    const second = () => {
        alert("greet");
    }
    return second; 
}

first()(); // does work


//Alternative
const secondTime = () => {
    const greet = "Hi";
    const second = () => {
        alert("greet");
    }
    return second(); 
}

secondTime();
```

Hope this works.